Why are the values of my ETH - RXS Swap so far off?
I recently swapped 2.692 ETH ($10,516.30 Value) to Rexas Finance (RXS) and, according to Coinbase Wallet received 65,661.533 RXS ($486.76 Value).  The Network fee says $10.31 * .00264 ETH which does not amount to the difference in value.  RXS is in presale and I went through their website (rexas.com) to purchase.  The presale stage was 10 at the time and the value was stated at 1 RXS = $0.150, this should have been equivalent to 70,108.667 RXS a difference of 4447.133 ($667.07 Value).  This doesn't account for the $10,029.54 in lost value and I'm trying to understand what is happening/happened here...
The transaction record on Coinbase Wallet shows a rate of 1 ETH = 528063.7787 RXS but by that logic I would think I'd have received 1,421,547.69 RXS.  So that's not adding up either.
I probably just missing something as I'm a little new to tokens and swaps so am looking for someone to help me understand.  Is the value for RXS on Coinbase Wallet just incorrect?  Did RXS not give me the correct amount of it's tokens?  Or is the value on Coinbase Wallet just showing the increase in value since my swap?  Or...?
Any help is very much appreciated.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about the price of a unlaunched token. Pricing is arbitrary, you should ask this to coinbase wallet or the token's devs.

I did the same however,now I think RXS is a sophisticated scam it's a fake project

I did the same few weeks ago. Swapping on coinbase wallet. $113 ETH, and i did get +2,360 RXS
So i payed less than 0.05 for 1 RXS
Not sure how, the only thing i can think of is that people are selling for less? Or i did something wrong.
Also you invest a lot, many people think it will be a scam. Because the owners did that before. I only did read it after buying.

I have about 17k RXS tokens in wallet and it now show a dollar amount changing daily. Thought it’s odd because it’s still in presale

Did anyone approach Coinbase and ask how their site us displaying RXS when it's not listed and is still in presale stage?

I asked that question the Rexas Finance support and this is what they answered me:
There seems to be a glitch with the coinbase pricing and we are working on it to be solved.
We are still in presale and the value for now should be seen as 0.
You can also check on etherscan and you will see 0 as we have not launched yet.
Don't worry the real price shall be displayed after we launch.

For me also same thing
I swapped ETH and got around 29k RXS and now shows $263/- in coin base

it’s cause they haven’t gone live. they try to track a value which is impossible. ur tokens x ur price at presale. for me 300k at .15 is the 48k. but displays 3600. tho my tokens r there. once they go live. that’s where the value will be put in correctly and from there up
